# Android Unit Test - retrofit and rxJava ,request never end

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am start began to learn unit test at android,
and i try to execute http request with Retrofit2 and RxJava2
but when i executing current request it never end.
Here is my TestCase code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
class LoginPageTestCase {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var testSchedulerRule = RxImmediateSchedulerRule()
    @Mock
    lateinit var view: UserLoginContract.LoginView
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var presenter: UserLoginPresenterImpl

    @Before
    fun `init mocks`() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun `1 valid fields`() {
        presenter.onAttach(view)
        assert(presenter.view.isNotNull())
    }

    @Test
    fun `2 try login`() {
        val loginRequest = LoginRequest("orij@test.co.il", "Aa123!!!")
        val loginRequestTestObserver = presenter.makeLoginRequest(loginRequest).test()
        loginRequestTestObserver.apply {
            awaitTerminalEvent()
            assertNoErrors()
            assertComplete()
            assertValueCount(1)
        }
        loginRequestTestObserver.assertNoErrors().assertValue { it.userData.isNotNull() }
        val userDetails = loginRequestTestObserver.values()[0]
        assert(userDetails.isNotNull())
        print("Show token: ${userDetails.userData.token}")
        backToMainThread()
    }
}
```

**RxImmediateSchedulerRule**:

```
class RxImmediateSchedulerRule : TestRule {

    override fun apply(base: Statement, d: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }

                try {
                    base.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: What i am trying to test is the real request and verify all fields.

Comment: Sounds more like an integration test rather than a unit test. Where exactly does your test hang?

Comment: Its not the same?, i need to get a token for continuation of testing...and about your question where my test hang i did not understood.